# Unfortunate, myAppName has stopped. Thread already started - Kotlin

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

I really need help here. I'm sorry to ask this that may look simple. It's about threads. I just start learning about it. I have looked all over the internet, but nothing solve my problem.

My app work when I start running it. But, if it loose focus and resume, it crash. It gives a "Unfortunately, myAppName has stopped." and I got "java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started".

This is my MainActivity:

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var snakeGame: SnakeGame? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val size = Point()
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        windowManager.defaultDisplay.getSize(size)
        snakeGame = SnakeGame(this, size)
        snakeGame?.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        setContentView(snakeGame)
    }


    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        snakeGame?.resume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        snakeGame?.pause()
    }
}
```

This is my GameView:

```
@SuppressLint("ViewConstructor")
class SnakeGame(context: Context, size: Point)
    : SurfaceView(context), Runnable {
    private lateinit var touchDown: Point
    private lateinit var arena: Arena
    private lateinit var snake: Snake
    private lateinit var food: Food

    private val bgColor = Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0)
    private val buttons = ArrayList<ControlButton>()
    private var gameThread = Thread(this)
    private val w = size.x
    private val h = size.y

    private var playing = false
    private var paused = true
    private var border = Rect()
    private var score = 0
    private var gameSpeed = 150


    override fun run() {
        var sameFrame = false
        var sfTime = 0L
        var acmTime: Long
        while (playing) {
            if (!paused) {
                if (sameFrame) {
                    acmTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - sfTime
                    if (acmTime > gameSpeed) {
                        update()
                        sameFrame = false
                    }
                } else {
                    sfTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    sameFrame = true
                }
            }
            draw()
        }
    }

    private fun setup() {
        arena = Arena(w - arenaCenter, h / 2, arenaW, arenaH)
        border = arena.sq
        snake = Snake(border.left, border.top)
        food = Food(border.left, border.top)
        if (buttons.size < 1) {
            createButtons(h)
        }
    }

    private fun update() {
        snake.update(border.left, border.top, border.right, border.bottom)
        if (snake.die()) {
            paused = true
        }
        if (snake.eat(food.fPos)) {
            food = Food(border.left, border.top)
            score++
        }
    }

    private fun draw() {
        if (holder.surface.isValid) {
            c = holder.lockCanvas()
            c.drawColor(bgColor)
            val paint = Paint().apply {
                color = Color.WHITE
                textSize = 70f
            }
            c.drawText("Score: $score", 20f, 50f, paint)

            arena.show()
            food.show()
            snake.show()
            for (cb in buttons) {
                cb.show()
            }
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c)
        }
    }

    fun pause() {
        playing = false
        try {
            gameThread.join()
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            Log.e("Error", "joining thread")
        }
    }

    fun resume() {
        playing = true
        setup()
        gameThread.start()
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you handling it in the onStop / onDestroy methods ? from the crash logs I can say that you are trying to start the Thread again which is already running.

Comment: A thread can only be started once for the lifetime of the thread - if it's your intention to let the game thread terminate in pause (playing = false followed by join) then the thread needs to be recreated in resume.

Comment: How do I do that? I am really lost about this. When I leave the app, I can't return to it.

Comment: It fails in `resume` at the line `gameThread.start()` - so just before that recreate the thread - as in `gameThread = Thread(this)`.

Comment: @Andy, that was it. Now I can understand and practice better. I still need to read more about threads, but this will help me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Because one thread can be started one time, but you call `.join()` method, which stops thread and then trying to start it second time.

If you want to pause thread you should change your `.pause()` and `.resume()` methods:

```
    fun pause() {
        paused = true
        //remove this block
        /*playing = false
        try {
            gameThread.join()
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            Log.e("Error", "joining thread")
        }*/
    }

    fun resume() {
        paused = false
        //setup() removing this too
        //gameThread.start()
    }
```

Also add methods `.startGame()` and `.stopGame()`:

```
   fun startGame() {
      setup()
      gameThread.start()  
   } 
   
   fun stopGame() {
      try {
        gameThread.join()
      } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
        Log.e("Error", "joining thread")
      }    
   }
```

And call these methods in activity's `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var snakeGame: SnakeGame? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val size = Point()
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        windowManager.defaultDisplay.getSize(size)
        snakeGame = SnakeGame(this, size)
        snakeGame?.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        setContentView(snakeGame)
        snakeGame?.startGame()
    }


    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        snakeGame?.resume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        snakeGame?.pause()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        snakeGame?.stopGame()
    }
}
```

`.stopGame()` method will close thread and free resources, when your activity is about die

Comment: This didn't work. With this fix, the app crash as soon as I leave it.

Comment: I will use this to improve my code, but I have to modify couple of things to make it work. Thanks for the quick reply! I will post the final version.